# HTML POST method correction

Tags: html, post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
function test(){
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"");
 document.write("&snumber="+snumber+"</h2><br />");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post">
<h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
Name :
<input type="text" id="name"><br/>
Student number:
<input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote a HTML code, I have to use HTML post method to send the data about name and number!! When I send this data, I can see properly but I cannot see POST message on my linux. When I use get method, I can see the GET message form linux like this.

[image: GET message]

Is my code not POST method? or how can I change it to the POST method without changing any outputs?

Thank you so much for your attention.!!

Comment: A form tag without an action attribute is not a form by standards. Try adding an action tag and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `method` attribute denotes whether a request will either be `GET` or `POST`, a form typically also requires an `action` attribute in order to be submitted. The `action` attribute can only be omitted in an HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE>` where the form is also intended to submit to the same page.

Your form was crashing for a few reasons:

1. because you missed the closing `</form>` tag, causing invalid HTML
2. your inputs were missing a `name` attribute, so their data wouldn't be sent through
3. you had no button with a type of `submit`

A form is typically submitted with an `<input type='submit'>`. Instead of this, you were attempting to hook a custom `submit` button up to a JavaScript function. `<input type='submit'>` automatically **creates** a button for you, which can be styled with the CSS selector `input[type=submit]`.

Note that while your JavaScript is wholly unnecessary, `document.write()` is [**vulnerable to XSS injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS), and should definitely **not** be used.

I've corrected your missing `</form>` tag, added the missing `name` attributes and added the missing form submission to the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <form action="target.php" method="post">
    <h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
    Name :
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br/> Student number:
    <input type="text" id="snumber" name="snumber"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

The data will get submitted with `POST` to the location specified in the form's `action`. In my example, that's `target.php`. If you want the form to post to **itself**, you can use `action="#"`, or simply omit the `action` attribute as you're using HTML5.

Obviously, you can point the form to any back-end script. Assuming you use PHP though, in your file `target.php`, you can output the data with:

```
echo $_POST['name'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
echo $_POST['snumber'] . PHP_EOL;
```

For further information on forms, check out the basics at [**MSDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form).

Hope this helps! :)